# Is $1+X^2$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

$N = 1 + X^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]$ , since
$1+0^2  = 1 $ and $1+1^2 = 1 + 2^2 = 2$.

Which means that $N$ can never be zero. Regarding the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem), $N$ is irreducible.

Is this sufficient to prove the irreducibility?

Comment: Absolutely .  Any factor of the quadratic would have to be linear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *general*, that is not enough. For example, consider the polynomial

$$ g(X) = 4X^2 + 4X + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}[X] $$

For every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, you have $g(a) \neq 0$. However, you also have the factorization $g(X) = (2X+1)^2$.

The ring $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$, however, is a field, and polynomials over a field are much better behaved. For example, every linear polynomial over a field has a root. Consequently, your example cannot have a linear factor.

<sub>*: I assume you are using the notation $\mathbb{Z}_3$ to mean the integers modulo $3$</sub>

Comment: Note: if you can't resist considering rational number roots of integer polynomials, then consider the same counterexample over the ring $\mathbb{Z} / 8 \mathbb{Z}$, which isn't a domain, and thus doesn't have a fraction field.

Comment: Thanks for that additional hint and for your answer of course.